# Use a SQL row as an array

Tags: php, sql

Here's the problem:

I got a row (voters) in my sql database containing nicknames of people who already voted like this:

```
"Nickname1", "Nickname2", "Nickname3",
```

But, if I try to use this row in an array to check if the logged in user already voted:

```
$voters = array($data['voters']);
if (!in_array($_SESSION['user'], $voters)) { // count his vote // } else { echo 'already voted' };
```

It simply doesn't work. If the user already voted but try anyway, his vote is counted and he's added again in my voters row.

What's wrong with my code ? Thanks

Comment: Your code is wrong because you don't have to use a single row to store multiple voters but instead you should have multiple rows each to store a single voter. Learn about database normalization or your work will be hard and fruitless

Comment: So I should create a new table "votes" ?

Comment: Yeah, or something similar. It's impossible to answer without the current structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong because you don't have to use a single row to store multiple voters but instead you should have multiple rows each to store a single voter. Learn about database normalization or your work will be hard and fruitless

Anyway, here's your solution

```
$voters = explode(",",$data['voters']);
if (!in_array('"'.$_SESSION['user'].'"', $voters)) { // do something... }
```

Comment: Yep it works.
But I'll create a new table, I don't know why I want to use a minimum of tables... strange.

Comment: @Osmoz don't worry, it's a normal idea for beginner database developers.

Answer (score 0):

You need like a table-in-table system. For it, you need a new table. Like that:

```
 |question_id|voter|
  223      |nickname1
  223      |nickname3
  225      |nickname1
```

And thus you can get an array of the voters for a spesific question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are creating an array over an array.

if print_r($voters) shows something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => "Nickname1", "Nickname2", "Nickname3"
)
```

try avoiding the array.

If not and $data['voters'] is a separated by commas string try using the explode function to generate an array

```
$voters = explode(",", $data['voters']);
```